# newlib support for 8 bit AVR MCUs

Tags: avr, newlib

I was trying to build a complete toolchain for avr 8 bit MCU from scratch. I am using latest sources of binutils, gcc and newlib. I was able to compile binutils and bootstrap gcc for target avr-unknown-none. But while trying to configure newlib for target avr-unknown-none, I am getting the below warning.

```
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
 target-newlib target-libgloss
(Any other directories should still work fine.)
```

The configure command I used is given below.

```
../configure --prefix=/home/varun/Tools/avr --target=avr-unknown-none --disable-nls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls
```

Running make after this does nothing.

There is another target namely avr32-unknown-none, which I believe is for 32 bit avrs. Setting the target as this while configuring doesn't produce any warnings.

So is 8 bit avr really supported by newlib...?

Answer (score 0):

Newlib won't work, use avr-libc

http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avr-libc/